# Mac Pro 3.1 with GTX 770 won't boot

Tags: upgrade, graphics, mac-pro

I was given a MacPro 2008 with 1 CPU, 1TB hard-drive, no wifi and 6GB of memory.

I patched via DosDude1's patch tool so enable NVME.

Current Specs: 2x4core 3.2Ghz. Wifi, 32GB of RAM, PCIe/NVMe Samsung 512GB.

Updated the OS to Mojave.
All is well. the machine is fast.

Tried to install the GPU (GTX 770), which is supposedly natively supported in Mojave

**Slot 1**- New GPU

**Slot 2**- PCI/NVMe

**Slot 3**- Old GPU

- With OLD out and monitor plugged into NEW - Nothing
- With OLD IN and NEW in , monitor plugged into OLD - Hangs at status bar 50%
- OLD IN, NEW OUT - Boots no problem

Answer (score 1):

There are no drivers for NVidia 3rd party cards in Mojave.
Support ended at High Sierra.

[MacVidCards - Which driver should I install for my new GPU?​](http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html) is pretty much the authority on this topic.

You can get to Mojave if you have a supported* ATI/AMD GPU with Metal capability, otherwise stay on High Sierra.

*Recommended GPU list, again from [MacVidCards - I want the best graphics card for my Mac Pro, where do I start?](http://www.macvidcards.com/i-want-the-best-graphics-card-for-my-mac-pro-where-do-i-start.html) No 3rd party drivers are needed for AMD cards, they still have Apple support - but only to Mojave, no further, for Mac Pro 3rd party cards.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I actually re-patched the OS from DosDude's utility and can now boot with the card in..and my system recognizes the card, but still no output from either HDMI or other ports. Nobody is being clear, but I do see a few videos where people are running the GTX 770 on Mojave and Catalina in 2008 Mac Pro.. I just ordered another 770 with 4GB and I'll take it from there (this one is patched to run as metal). I'll going to go through the trouble of testing my wires to make sure I'm getting the proper voltage to the card as well and update here as it may be helpful to someone .

Comment: Ah, OK. Wish you luck. I've never actually tried the DosDude patchers, I've left most of my Pros at their last supported OS. Only my 4,1/5,1 which I put a supported AMD GPU in has been updated as far as Mojave.

Comment: Wow.. I should win doofus of the year award. New card came in, same problem, but this guy sent wires, which forced me to change the wires that I bought.  On the board, there are (2) 6 pin power outlets. If you bend down and look closely on the board, one power port is labelled "pci" and the other is labelled "boost".  "pci" goes to the 8 port power plug on the card, and the "boost" should go to the 6 port plug. I then took out the new wires and plugged in the old ones I had, plugged them in and everything came up. Btw.. thank you for responding !!!